# File upload plugin and display for a web site application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that uses twitter bootstrap and I would like to add a place for "shared files" (word docs, videos, etc) that each user who uses the application can upload their own files to and it can be shared among users of the entire website. Everyone can view each file. The first thing that came to mind is a youtube account, where you can upload a video and then see all of your uploaded videos and everyone else can view it. I need this, but for all types of files and any user of the application can edit it.

By myself, I'm not sure how to achieve this, so I was searching for a plugin. Obviously I'm not sure if something like this has a particular name so all of my google searches have so far come up empty. Does anyone have any suggestions? Does the functionality I want have a name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox.com comes to mind.

They have an API chooser where users can upload through the web site:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js

How to share files and folders
https://www.dropbox.com/help/274/en

Look through their Sharing Q&A
https://www.dropbox.com/help/category/Sharing

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will look into this. Not sure if this is the right way to go yet, so more suggestions are certainly welcome!

Comment: I was looking at dropbox chooser, google picker, and owncloud after your suggestion. We decided to go with a Sharepoint link. Thanks for the suggestion.